# Concept class containing function with exact enum function arguments c++20

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to create a concept that narrows down what kind of classes can be used with predefined function types. I managed to figure out how to use a concept for the return type, but I'm still struggling to not allow implicit casting for the function arguments. Especially with an enum. The enum is defined as:

```
typedef enum GpioLevel {
    LOW, HIGH
} GpioLevel;
```

Currently my (a bit messy) concept looks like the following:

```
template <typename P>
concept pinConcept = requires (GpioLevel level) {
  P::Write(level);
  requires std::same_as<std::underlying_type_t<decltype(level)>,std::underlying_type_t<GpioLevel>>;
  P::Write(std::declval<GpioLevel>());
  {P::GetLevel()} -> std::same_as<GpioLevel>;
};
```

Then a class that should adhere to the concept would be:

```
class PinTemplate {
public:
    static inline void Write(double level) {
        std::cout<<"Writing "<<std::to_string(level) <<std::endl;
    }
    static inline GpioLevel GetLevel() {
        return GpioLevel::HIGH;
    }
};
```

This should never be accepted by my concept, as the Write function uses a double instead of a GpioLevel. However I runs just fine with many errornous data:

```
template <pinConcept pin>
class SpiPinPort {
public:
    void WriteData(){
        pin::Write(GpioLevel::LOW);
        // Below should actually not be allowed, but somehow it just casts it
        pin::Write(5);
        pin::Write('a');
    }
};

int main()
{
    SpiPinPort<PinTemplate> port;
    port.WriteData();
}
```

This gives me an output of:
*Writing 0.000000* 
*Writing 5.000000* 
*Writing 97.000000*

However I would expect a compile error on instantiation of the SpiPinPort, since PinTemplate doers not adhere to the pinConcept concept. If I change the signature of the  PinTemplate class from double to GpioLevel it does throw some errors (as I would expect and hope). But I want to restraint the possibility of allowing a template class with wrong function templates.

https://godbolt.org/z/v587aqcco

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's run through your concept real quick:

```cpp
template <typename P>
concept pinConcept = requires (GpioLevel level) {
  P::Write(level);
  requires std::same_as<std::underlying_type_t<decltype(level)>,std::underlying_type_t<GpioLevel>>;
  P::Write(std::declval<GpioLevel>());
  {P::GetLevel()} -> std::same_as<GpioLevel>;
};
```

That second requirement:

```cpp
requires std::same_as<std::underlying_type_t<decltype(level)>,std::underlying_type_t<GpioLevel>>;
```

`decltype(level)` is `GpioLevel`, so this is checking that two different spellings of the same type are the same. Which, of course they are. This requirement doesn't actually do anything.

The third requirement:

```cpp
P::Write(std::declval<GpioLevel>());
```

You very rarely need to use `declval` in concepts because the requires expression lets you introduce parameters. And in this case you already have a `GpioLevel` handy - that's `level`. And this is already what you're checking in the first requirement.

Now, there *is* a difference: `P::Write(level)` is checking that you can call `Write` with an lvalue `GpioLevel` and `P::Write(std::declval<GpioLevel>())` is checking that you can call `Write` with an xvalue `GpioLevel`. But I really doubt that's what you're going for, or that this distinction matters here.

So the whole thing can just be:

```cpp
template <typename P>
concept pinConcept = requires (GpioLevel level) {
  P::Write(level);
  {P::GetLevel()} -> std::same_as<GpioLevel>;
};
```

---

That said, the requirement `P::Write(level)` isn't checking anything about *types*. It's checking the *expression*. Can you call `P::Write` with a `GpioLevel`?

Now, `GpioLevel` is an unscoped enum. Which means this is totally fine:

```cpp
int main() {
    // some function taking a double
    auto f = [](double){};

    f(LOW); // ok
}
```

That is okay, so `PinTemplate::Write(LOW)` (despite `Write` taking a `double`) is also okay, so `PinTemplate` satisfies `pinConcept`.

The best way to fix this is to change `GpioLevel` to be a scoped enum:

```cpp
enum class GpioLevel { LOW, HIGH }
```

And now `GpioLevel` isn't convertible to `double`, so `PinTemplate` no longer satisfies `pinConcept`.

---

If that's not an option, then your only other approach is to instead check that `P::Write` is a static function with specific type:

```cpp
requires std::same_as<decltype(P::Write), void(GpioLevel)>;
```

This is more limiting, since now `P::Write` cannot be a function template or having defaulted function parameters.